# centering a \hbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to center a collection of nested `\hbox` and `\vbox` without any succes :-(

Here is the code I use:

```
\begin{figure}[h] 
\center{
  \vbox{\hbox{%
    \includegraphics{imageA}~%
    \includegraphics{imageB}~%
    \includegraphics{imageC}}%
    \hbox{% 
     \includegraphics{imageD}~%
     \includegraphics{imageE}~%
     \includegraphics{imageF}}}%
     \caption{text}
 }
\end{figure}
```

[image: Here, you can see the result that I have obtained]

The desirable result will be with this image centered in the middle of the page.

Comment: My problem is that I need to use the specific syntaxis I provided, I have to use the tex commands \vbox and \hbox. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you forced to use `\hbox` and `\vbox`?

Comment: @user17888 why are you forced to use a syntax that doesn't work instead of the syntax in either of the posted answers that does work? If you _are_ forced to use commands that don't work then we can not help.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Neither `\hbox` nor `\vbox` are supported LaTeX commands for use in a document, and `\center` is the internal command for the `center` environment (and doesn't take an argument.) Also don't use `[h]` on its own as it makes it very hard for LaTeX to find a 
good place for the float so most likely it will go to the end of the document.

```
\begin{figure}[hpt] 
\centering
\includegraphics{imageA}~%
\includegraphics{imageB}~%
\includegraphics{imageC}%

 \includegraphics{imageD}~%
 \includegraphics{imageE}~%
 \includegraphics{imageF}%
 \caption{text}

\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 5):

You might be better off using a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\mybone{\tikz{\fill[blue!20] (0,0) rectangle (1,2);}}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \mybone & \mybone & \mybone \\
    \mybone & \mybone & \mybone 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Error of the algorithm measured against a hand-made segmentation of the Metatarsal%
\ldots why am I kidding? I don't know what I'm talking about\ldots}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to understand why you're forced to use an unsupported syntax.

However the problem is that `\vbox` doesn't start horizontal mode, so no matter what `\centering` or other declaration you give, the `\vbox` will be placed at the left margin; it's just the same feature you're using inside the `\vbox`: the two `\hbox`es are piled one above the other because they don't start horizontal mode. Adding `\leavevmode` will do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\hbox{%
    \includegraphics{imageA}
    \includegraphics{imageB}
    \includegraphics{imageC}}
    \hbox{%
     \includegraphics{imageD}
     \includegraphics{imageE}
     \includegraphics{imageF}}
     \caption{text}
 }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The `\center` command is wrong. I've also removed useless `~` and `%`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the different answers. In thi end, I solved it, adding a minipage environment which encapsulates all the tex commands.